# How to conform to Codable and using Realm in swift 4 when class has a array of string?

Tags: realm, swift4, codable

My class has a property [String], I wanna using Codable and Realm.

JSON is

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "title": "title",
    "pictureList": [ 
        "String 1",
        "String 2",
        "String 3"
     ]
}
```

The class

```
class News: Object, Decodable{
    @objc dynamic var name: String!
    @objc dynamic var title: String!

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, title       
    }
}
```

It can works do like this [another solution](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5437)

But in this way I have to write a few codes like **name = try container.decode(Type, forKey)** in func **init(from decoder: ) throws**

Is there any way to meet the goal without the func **init(from decoder: ) throws** and just let it decode automatically.

My assumption is add a class like **Picture**

```
class News: Object, Decodable{
    @objc dynamic var name: String!
    @objc dynamic var title: String!

    @objc dynamic var pictureList: Picture

    class Picture: Object, Decodable {    
        var pictureList: [String]!

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case pictureList
        }
        public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            pictureList = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .pictureList) ?? [""]
        }
    }
}
```

but I can't finish it correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your Realm version?

Comment: Why all the types are `T!` instead of `T` or `T?`?

Comment: You cannot nest Realm model object classes, and you cannot use Swift's `Array<T>` type as a property on such a class.

Comment: @user28434 **T!** means force to unwrap the value, but it will crash when **T** is nil [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Comment: @magic_9527, i know what it means, but why did you used it? `T!` is inferior to to both `T`('cos there's no guarantee of value, and it will crash) and `T?`('cos it will crash on nil).